# git merge command renames the file to original value

Tags: git, git-merge

I must be doing something wrong. There are `2` branches, `develop` and `feature`.

I decided to start `feature` branch and implement some radical changes. This includes renaming the files (changing file name and path) and content inside. Content change roughly 30-40%.

During that time, `develop` branch continued with new code dvp and then merge `feature -> develop` happened.

During merge, `feature` to `develop`, for some reason, git renamed new files from `feature` branch to the name they were used to be in the `develop` branch. According to the git Extension GUI I use, it seems that git detected the filepath change (from file content similarities?).

What could be the reason that git nonchalant thought it can change the file name and paths. This indeed destroyed build since in C language, `#include "file.."` was not found anymore.

[image: paths in brackets are those that were used on feature branch. New path, outside bracket, is the new file name, and the file name from develop branch]

Comment: If you want to change only a few things when merging, you can run git-merge with `--no-commit --no-ff` to stop right before creating the merge commit. You can then do your changes (like re-renaming the file for example) and then run `git commit` or `git commit --no-edit` to conclude the merge.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem in the end? What solution worked?

Comment: No - I do not know why this happens. I had to manually correct all files.

Answer (score 0):

Both `git diff` and `git merge` consider a removed file and an added file with a similar of 50% to be a rename, by default. I agree, this seems like much too low a default threshold, but it often works fine.

The two commands support the `--find-renames=NN%` switch to adjust this threshold. `--find-renames=100%` would require the added and removed files to be identical before being considered a rename, and that's probably what you need. `--find-renames=90%` might work too.

Refs: look for `--find-rename` in

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff and
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Comment: Good info - didn't know that. I tried the very empty repository. First commit on `main` branch with `file.txt` content `File on main branch` + commit. A `feature` branch started from there and I moved the file into `folder/fileA.txt`. File content changed to `File on f1 branch`. When doing merge back to main branch, there was no *rename* detection. (a change was one word, certainly below 50%, unless it looks at number of lines..).

Comment: I suspect there has something to do with the fact that 2 branches have been in // added with new commits together, and potentially at the same file, that existed in one branch, but not in another..

Comment: You example with `File on f1 branch` vs `File on main branch` is actually 0% overlap, because it's counting the number of identical lines, not bytes or words. At least that's my understanding, but the manual is not explicit about that, so I could be wrong.